# How can I compare an NCHAR value representing a number with an actual NUMBER?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which contains entries every time an order is updated; it's sort of like an audit log. I have another table which stores the last batch ID I looked at.

I want to have a query that returns only values from the audit table which have a batch ID greater then my stored batch ID.

My issue is that the column holding the batch ID in my audit table (F4201z1.SYEDBT) is NCHAR(15) data type, and the column holding the last batch ID in the other table (F0002.NNN005) is a NUMBER type.

```
Select SYDOCO from crpdta.F4201z1 
where SYEDBT >
  (Select NNN005 from crpCTL.F0002 where NNSY = '55')
and SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT'
```

The above is my first run at the query, it returns the expected 6 results from my test DB, but it takes 30 seconds. This is too long as the table in production will grow very quickly.

```
Select SYDOCO from crpdta.F4201z1
where SYEDBT >
  (Select Cast(NNN005 as Nchar(15)) as NNN005 from crpCTL.F0002 where NNSY = '55')
and SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT'
```

This was my second crack at it and returns the initial 50 results in 0.39 seconds, but it returns 220k results in total which is not right.

What I know so far is that SYEDBT is an indexed column. In the first code sample above it won't use that index and does a full table scan taking 40 seconds or so.

In the second code sample it uses the index but it's comparing NCHAR values and so it works off of [the Oracle rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm) where it compares one character at a time and the first difference it runs into within the character set it assigns which is 'bigger'.

Is there a way for me to compare these two values while still making use of the index on the F4201z1 table in order to keep the time down, without changing the structures of the tables I am using?

Comment: Are you able to add a function-based index against F4201z1 - or would that count as a structural change? (Why are you storing a number in a string field anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query is hitting the existing index but using character comparison, as you've realised. While you could manipulate the SYEDBT value - if not by converting to a number, then perhaps trimming and left-padding with spaces, which is also ugly - that would prevent the index being used, and that would also revert to a full table scan.

Your first query is implicitly converting each SYEDBT value from nchar to number, before comparing that converted value to the NNN005 numeric value. It's doing a full table scan to do that.

The only way to really avoid that, if you can't change the table structure, is to add a function-based index:

```
create index F4201z1_fbi on F4201z1(to_number(SYEDBT));
```

You can then query with a matching explicit conversion:

```
Select SYDOCO from F4201z1
where to_number(SYEDBT) > (Select NNN005 from F0002 where NNSY = '55')
and SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT';
```

and that will hit your new index.

If you're storing different types of data in SYEDBT then <strike>you shouldn't be</strike> you may have values that cannot be converted to numbers, which make the index and query fail with ORA-01722. You can make the index more selective:

```
create index F4201z1_fbi on F4201z1(
  case when SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT' then to_number(SYEDBT) end);
```

where the values are only converted for a specific SYTYTN (or one of several if you have other numeric values you might want to look at); but then that has to be exactly duplicated in the query too:

```
Select SYDOCO from F4201z1
where case when SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT' then to_number(SYEDBT) end >
  (Select NNN005 from F0002 where NNSY = '55')
and SYTYTN = 'JDESOOUT';
```

Which gets even messier if there are more 'number' cases, and changing the index to add new ones would mean all queries relying on the index would also have to be modified. It would be cleaner to add a virtual column to the table with the same logic, and then index that virtual column. But that changes the table structure.

Comment: That will solve my issue, I have to present the solution to my Manager first as it will eventually hit our production, but the DBA in the building has also said this is the best solution :) thank you!

Comment: Also we are not storing different types it's all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the index on the column SYEDBT the compared value must be of the same type (i.e. NUMBER). Use a to_number conversion in your subquery:

```
(Select  to_number(NNN005) from crpCTL.F0002 ...
```

Comment: NNN0005 seems to be a number already; it's SYEDBT that's nchar and indexed. I think...

Comment: the NNN005 is the number, it's the SYEDBT which is Nchar

Comment: uh eh, got it wrong, @Alex thanks for the correction. I updated the question, so that the types of columns are obvious.